# Nesting a ScrollView inside a TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-tablelayout

My intention is to make my `TextView` scrollable by nesting it inside a `ScrollView` (although I know that `TextView` can be made scrollable on its own (without needing a parent `ScrollView`), I wanted to do it in this way :) ) and have the `ScrollView` fill the entire width of the screen.

The layout in the following code works, but the `ScrollView` does not fill the entire width of the screen. However, its parent `TableRow` fills the entire width.

I have tried substituting the values of `android:layout_width` of `ScrollView` with `fill_parent`, `match_parent` and `wrap_content` but none of them are filling the width completely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my">

    <TableRow>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_box"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution! I added `android:layout_weight="1"` to `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_box"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</ScrollView>
```